# Excel: Why use an XLA and not just a blank XLS?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, macros, vba

Someone has put lots of Macros in blank XLS documents, and now someone has aked me to put them into an XLA document. Why and for what purpose?

The Macro's loop through opening workbooks and copy/pasting their data into the active workbook; and then saving as.

What's the benefits of an XLA?

Cheers

Mike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XLA can be defined as **MS Excel Add-in** file format. Add-ins provide an excellent way of increasing the power of Excel and they are the ideal vehicle for distributing your custom functions. XLA format is meant for saving functions that can be shared by many other workbooks, it's not meant for saving workbooks.

Comment: So you would have your macros  (code) in separate XLA's and then have a separate workbook call those XLA's when required. That way it's easier to manage upates and 'DRY' principles. So all my colleague needed to do was save as XLA rather than XLS?

Comment: Apparently yes.